# crash after jointDef.Initialize in box2d cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, box2d

I have a ship and a dock and would like to have a joint connecting them when I press on the dock

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

if (_dockFixture->TestPoint(locationWorld)) {

    b2DistanceJointDef _myJDef;
    _myJDef.Initialize(_shipBody, _dockBody, _shipBody->GetWorldCenter(),_dockBody->GetWorldCenter());
    (b2DistanceJoint*) _world->CreateJoint(&_myJDef);

}
```

}

As soon as I click on the dock, cocos2d and the IPhone Simualtor crash without a log in the concole....

I'm a newbie, what might be wrong? Should I also post the code of the two bodies?

Answer (score 0):

Run your application in debug mode. When your application will crash - run a debugger and view a callstack to determine the place where is the problem